# Cannot access api-docs of microservice from spring cloud gateway. Failed to load API definition

Tags: swagger, spring-cloud-gateway, springfox

I'm trying to link my microservices to my gateway. , but I'm not able to access the api-docs of my microservice through the gateway.

Error from Swagger-UI:

```
Failed to load API definition
Fetch error
Not Found http://localhost:8080/microservice/v2/api-docs
```

Swagger version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I can `GET` the api-docs through the the microservice directly (port 8081):

```
http://localhost:8081/v2/api-docs
```

But I'm not able to do it through the gateway (port 8080):

```
http://localhost:8080/microservice/v2/api-docs
```

Microservice's properties:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: microservice

server:
  port: 5082
...
```

Gateway's properties:

```
server:
  port: 2443

spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: microservice
        uri: lb://microservice
        predicates:
        - Path=/microservice/**
...
```

The workaround that I've found is to add a `@GetMapping` in my `Controller.java` to point the URL specifically to the `api-docs` (but I'm pretty sure this is not the proper solution).

```
WebClient webClient;

@ResponseBody
@GetMapping(value = "/v2/api-docs")
public String getApiDocs()
{
    factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory("http://localhost:8081");
    factory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE);
    
    this.webClient = WebClient
              .builder()
              .uriBuilderFactory(factory)
              .build();

    return webClient.get()
        .uri("/v2/api-docs")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .block();
}
```

FYI:

- The microservice and gateway are both registered with Eureka.
- I can access the `api-docs` of the gateway just fine, but not the `api-docs` of the microservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the gateway is not configured to load swagger associated resources (UI, config files).
I will use in the explanation gateway config using **@Configuration** class, but probably it can be used in the properties file as well.

1. Specify for each service a custom Swagger API path. So it can be used to configure routing in the gateway in the next steps. It will add prefix **/microservice1-api** in the path for the swagger UI URL and swagger JSON configuration file.

```yaml
springdoc:
      api-docs:
        path: /microservice1-api
      swagger-ui:
        path: /api.html
```

2. Specify the route to each prefix in the gateway config. So it will be properly route paths associated with service swagger resources.

```java
    RouteLocatorBuilder.Builder apiDocJsonRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder.Builder builder) {
    //uri can be actual URI or load balancer path
            return builder
                    .route(p -> p.path( "/microservice1-api/**").uri("microservice1"))
                    .route(p -> p.path( "/microservice2-api/**").uri("microservice2"))
                    .route(p -> p.path("/microservice3-api/**").uri("microservice3"));
        }
```

3. You have to define routing for **/swagger-ui/index.html** path to proper service. In this case path to service is recognized by URL parameter **configUrl**. After Step 1 if you open swagger in the browser, you will see that at the end of address line you have parameter **?configUrl=/microservice1-api/swagger-config**. So if this parameter value has prefix associated with a specific service, you can use it for routing.

```java
RouteLocatorBuilder.Builder apiDocUIRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder.Builder builder) {
        return builder
                .route(p -> swaggerUi(p, "microservice1", "/microservice1-api/swagger-config"))
                .route(p -> swaggerUi(p, "microservice2", "/microservice2-api/swagger-config"))
                .route(p -> swaggerUi(p, "microservice3", "/microservice3-api/swagger-config"));
    }


    private Buildable<Route> swaggerUi(PredicateSpec p, String service, String expectedValue) {
        return p.path("/swagger-ui/index.html").and().query("configUrl", expectedValue)
                .uri(service);
    }
```

4. Open API in the browser using  http://***gateway_path***/**microservice_route**/api.html

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for answering. This issue happened sometime ago and it was resolved, but my solution seems similar to yours.

Comment: I saw a reference to your question from a fresh question, So I decided to make an answer here since you have a more detailed issue explanation :)