# Cannot access api-docs of microservice, spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, maven, swagger, microservices, swagger-ui

I basically have the exact same problem as this user's question:
[Cannot access api-docs of microservice from spring cloud gateway. Failed to load API definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71108572/cannot-access-api-docs-of-microservice-from-spring-cloud-gateway-failed-to-load)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered in the post that you mention.
Try to follow my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71996847/18936800